# How can I access this from an event handling function?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am binding a DOM event to an event-handling function (cf. below). This binding happens in a child component that needs to call its parent class, through `this.parent`.

My problem is, of course, that being in such a function rebinds `this` to the object on which the event was fired (in that case, that's `#document`). That prevents me from doing `this.parent` inside the function itself, and I can't change the function prototype. **What can I do to keep track of the original `this` in the `_keydownHandler(e)` function?** (Yes, I heard of arrow functions but it's not an option here)

Code here:

```
"use strict";

export class EventHandler {
  constructor(parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
  }

  bindEvent() {
    document.onkeydown = SomeOtherClass.keydownHandler;
  }

  printParentValue() {
    console.log("Value from child:", this.parent.someValue);
  }

  callParentFn() {
    this.parent.someFn();
  }
}

class SomeOtherClass {
  keydownHandler(e) {
    console.log(this.parent.someValue); // I want to access the EventHandler's parent from there
  }
}
```

The Parent goes roughly like this:

```
"use strict";

import { EventHandler } from "./events.js";

class Parent {
  constructor() {
    this.someValue = 3;
    this.eH = new EventHandler(this);
    this.eH.bindEvent();
  }

  someFn() {
    console.log("Value from parent:", this.someValue);
  }

  test() {
    this.eH.printParentValue();
    this.eH.callParentFn();
  }
}
const parent = new Parent();
parent.test();
```

As expected, the `parent.test()` method goes fine, but I can't access `Parent.someValue` from `_keydownHandler(e)`.

Comment: Why is: `onkeydown = (e)=>this._keydownHandler(e);` not an option? Have you tried using the other methods like binding `this._keydownHandler.bind(this)` or setting your class up as an [`EventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener)

Comment: where is the `Child` class?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Because I would like to refer to a function that is not in the `EventHandler` class.

Comment: @IronyStack sorry, fixed

Comment: Then your question needs to reflect that, we cant provide a proper solution if your example doesnt match your code as close as possible. For instance if `_keydownHandler` is supposed to be some outside method where is it from and how would your class know about it

Comment: where are the method 
       `this.eH.printParentValue();`
`this.eH.callParentFn();` defined?

Comment: if your code runs as given and we execute `this.eH._keydownHandler()` `inside` test method it works perfectly fine.so you need to be briefed about your problem that you are facing

Comment: @PatrickEvans I changed the code to reflect that. Actually your `.bind(this)` fixed my problem, thanks.

Comment: @IronyStack in my browser I get a `Cannot read property 'someValue' of undefined`, due to the `this` rebinding.

Comment: thats not how it works, you are breaking the flow, and the error is not about access it simple says the `this.parent` inside `SomeOtherClass` is `undefined` and that is actually `undefined` according to the code shown for that class

Comment: @IronyStack What flow? Indeed, `this` is rebound so `this.parent` is undefined.

Comment: @fff_ so simple if `this.parent` is undefined how could `this.parent.someValue` can contain value